# Finding a specific text in a string of text in a single cell (using IFS function?)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a single cell that contains several sets of text separated by a semi colon (extracted from another application) for example

Cell A1: apple;banana;orange
Cell A2: banana;orange;melon

I am trying to introduce a formula in an adjacent cell which will return a value for apple if it contains apple, or banana if it contains banana.

I am happy to have it only return a single value (the first one perhaps)

I tried the IF function using <> as suggested on the internet.
I thought this had worked to start with but then it didnt return the value when I moved it! - so it was clearly wrong.

=IF(A1<>"apple","apple","") - returned apple - but then always returned apple even if there was no apple in the string.

I did then try an IFS nested statement - but that didnt work - highly likely because I then realised that even my IF statement didnt work properly.
I tried to research ISNUMBER and a couple of other suggestions but cant seem to get it anywhere near working!

It seems like it is something relatively straightforward and I am just missing the obvious - would welcome any assistance.

Comment: So which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Enterprise 365 version 2210 Build 15726.20174

Comment: `=IF(A1<>"apple","apple","")` just checks if the **whole** cell is distinct to string `apple`. That explains why returns apple even if there is no apple in the string. Check functions like COUNTIF with wild criteria or [SEARCH](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/search-searchb-functions-9ab04538-0e55-4719-a72e-b6f54513b495) may be helpful. Also, pretty sure you can used advanced functions from Office 365 to get the desired output

Comment: Sorry, it might be my lack of knowledge but I cant get anywhere near with COUNTIF either

Comment: I have got to a point where I can return the value for apple by using =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("apple",A1)),"apple","no") - but I really need to be able to return more than 1 potential field - but dont think i can nest this formula

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("apple",D365)),"apple",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("melon",D365)),"melon","no"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of items to search (in this example, I put that list in cells E2:E4).  Then in cell B1 and copied down is this formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,REPT($E$2:$E$4,COUNTIF(A1,"*"&$E$2:$E$4&"*")))
```

[image]